# How destroy SelectionKey attachment? attach(null) doesn't work

Tags: java, tcp, memory-leaks, nio

My java application has memory leaks - when my resources clearing code is executing task manager shows that memory usage wasn't changed. My code

```
while (isRunning) {
      try 
      {

             selector.select(); 

             long sum=0;

             Set keys =  selector.selectedKeys();
             Iterator it = keys.iterator(); 
             while(it.hasNext())
             {
                 SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey)it.next();
                 if (key.isReadable())
                 { 
                      SocketChannel sc = (SocketChannel) key.channel();

                      ByteBuffer bb;
                      if(key.attachment()==null)
                      {
                          bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024*1024);
                          key.attach(bb);
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          bb = (ByteBuffer)key.attachment();
                          bb.clear();
                      }

                      int x =  sc.read(bb); 

                       System.out.println(x +" bytes were read");
                       if(x==-1)
                       {
                           key.attach(null); //doesn't work
                           sc.close();
                           //bb = null; // also doesn't work
                       }
                 } 
             }
           keys.clear();
      } 
      catch (Exception ex) 
      {     
          ex.printStackTrace(new PrintStream(System.out));
      }
      finally
      { 
            //stopServer();
      }
    }
```

Testing logic - I wrote simple TCP client java programm sending 100 messages to server. I intentionally allocated large buffer  - 1MB for each connection. When client finishes his job `int x =  sc.read(bb);` returns -1 and the following code is executed:

```
if(x==-1)
                           {
                               key.attach(null); //doesn't work
                               sc.close();
                               //bb = null; // also doesn't work
                           }
```

I checked it with debug output, this code was really executed but task manager still showes large memory usage. where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly `key.attach(null)` works. If it didn't, attaching a non-null object wouldn't work either. Same code.

But, in any case, closing the `SocketChannel` cancels the key, which removes it from all key sets of all `Selectors` it was registered with, so you will never see the key again anyway, so it becomes eligible for GC, and so does the attachment, regardless of whether you call `key.attach(null)` or not, which is therefore redundant. Either you have another reference to your attachment somewhere else, or your memory usage problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Memory profiler shows that attached objects really disappears - 'Max used heap size' decreases when client application finishes. But there is also 'Max heap size' which remains large and task manager shows this parameter.  How I can reduce 'max heap size'? It looks strange that 'used heap size' decreased but 'heap size' didn't.

Comment: Just as I said. Now your question is about heaps and garbage collection. I suggest you start a new one. This one has had it.